# Loading a checkpoint from a trained model using estimator

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow-estimator

I want to do very simple task. Let us assume that I have executed a model and saved multiple checkpoints and metada for this model using tf.estimator. We can again assume that I have 3 checkpoints. 1, 2 and 3. While I am evaluating the trained results on the tensorboard, I am realizing that checkpoint 2 is providing the better weights for my objective.

Therefore I want to load checkpoint 2 and make my predictions. What I want to ask simply is that, is it possible to delete checkpoint 3 from the model dir and let the estimator load it automatically from checkpoint 2 or is there anything I can do to load a specific checkpoint for.my predictions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can. By default, Estimator will load latest available checkpoint in `model_dir`. So you can either delete files manually, or specify checkpoint file with

```
warm_start = tf.estimator.WarmStartSettings(ckpt_to_initialize_from='file.ckpt')
```

and pass this to estimator

```
tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_fn,
                       config=run_config,
                       model_dir='dir',
                       warm_start_from=warm_start)
```

The latter option will not mess tensorboard summaries, so it's generally cleaner